# write data in some text

Tags: javascript

i have following code

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function writeit()
{
    var tbox = document.getElementById('a_tbox_1');
    if (tbox)
    {
        tbox.value = '';
    }
    tbox = document.getElementById('a_tbox_2');
    if (tbox)
    {
        tbox.value = '';
    }
}
</script>

<form name="a_form">
Product name:
  <input type="text" id="a_tbox_1" name="a_tbox" value="" />

  price : <input type="text" id="a_tbox_2" name="a_tbox" value="" />
<input type="button" name="btn" value="write it" onclick="writeit()" />
</form>

</html>
```

main idea of program is that i should give me possibilites to write two value  product name and price and  click after write ii it should write these informations in some text how to do it?please help

Comment: Where do you want that information to be written to? Alert window? Text box? Server?

Comment: in some text document on the same computer

Comment: You can't write/save text documents/files on the client computer through JavaScript if thats what you mean.

Comment: You could put it in a popup window so the user can save or print it...

Comment: @BGerrissen, the only way you can write a files on the client's computer with JavaScript is only via cookies.

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeit()
{
    var strValue = '';
    var tbox = document.getElementById('a_tbox_1');
    if (tbox)
    {
        //tbox.value = '';
        // add:
        strValue = 'name: ' + tbox.value;
    }
    if(strValue != '')
        strValue += ', ';
    tbox = document.getElementById('a_tbox_2');
    if (tbox)
    {
        //tbox.value = '';
        // add:
        strValue += 'price: ' + tbox.value + ' € :)';
    }
    alert(strValue);
    // or do whatever you want with it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questin is not clear, but try the code below and see if its what you are looking for:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function writeit() {
    var tbox = document.getElementById('a_tbox_1'), tbox2 = document.getElementById('a_tbox_2');
    if (tbox.value && tbox2.value){
         alert('product = ' + tbox.value + " :: price = " + tbox2.value);

         // sendData('action.php?product=' + tbox.value + '&price=' + tbox2.value); (you can send your data via ajax)

        tbox.value = ''; 
        tbox2.value = '';
        return false;
    }
}  
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form name="a_form">
      Product name: <input type="text" id="a_tbox_1" name="a_tbox" value="" />
      Price : <input type="text" id="a_tbox_2" name="a_tbox" value="" />
      <input type="button" name="btn" value="write it" onclick="writeit()" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```